# How does Slackware Login quotes work?

Tags: ssh, email, login, slackware

I'm new to Slackware and I think It's beautiful Distro.
When I login it with ssh it prints motd, quote and a line for informing mail like this

```
Linux 3.10.17.
Last login: Thu Oct 23 06:28:08 +0330 2014 on /dev/pts/0.
No mail.

"The other day I put instant coffee in my microwave oven ... I almost
went back in time."
            -- Steven Wright

ahmad@SLKW:/$
```

I want to know how does the quotes and mail messages work and where are the config files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm an Arch user, never used Slackware.)

The program that prints the quotes is usually called [`fortune`](http://linux.die.net/man/6/fortune). It's available on most distros I have used, but the specific set of quotes may vary. Look in `/etc/profile`, or in scripts in `/etc/profile.d` for mentions of `fortune`. According to the description of the [`bsd-games`](http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=bsd-games-2.13-i486-12.txz) package:

> Adds a call to 'fortune' to /etc/profile.d/ so that users will get a fortune message when they log in.

The mail message is usually printed by [`pam_mail`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mail), a PAM plugin, but I think Slackware does not use PAM ([What are the reasons Slackware still refuses to include PAM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33685/70524)).

According to [this Linux Questions forum post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-disable-mail-notification-at-console-login-933971/) for Slackware 14, the mail notification is also printed due to commands in `/etc/profile`:

> ```
> ...
> # Notify user of incoming mail.  This can be overridden in the user's
> # local startup file (~/.bash.login or whatever, depending on the shell)
> if [ -x /usr/bin/biff ]; then
>  biff y 2> /dev/null
> fi
> ...
> ```